# BeautifulSoup4 - ожидание загрузки страницы

Tags: html, python, парсер, beautiful-soup

При парсинге страницы я столкнулся с такой проблемой что нужный мне блок загружается только после загрузки основного контента и мне передается DOM без нужного блока.

Есть ли в библиотеке Beautiful Soup функционал позволяющий дождаться полной загрузки сайта и только после этого отправить DOM?

Или другие способы реализовать нужный мне функционал...

Comment: Вам нужен `selenium`.

Comment: Для начала откройте инструменты разработчика в браузере и во вкладке `Network` > `XHR`посмотрите какие запросы делаются после загрузки основной страницы. Возможно, там найдете откуда тянутся нужные вам данные. Другие варианты - Selenium и [Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/#javascript-support)